# Does reciting Surah Mulk for someone protect them from the torment of the grave? What about non-Muslims?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, dua, surah

Salam, I was wondering basically Surah Mulk saves you from the torment of the grave if read before passing away.

If you read and blow on a non-Muslim would that count as reading it and will the effect be the same on a non-Muslim?

Comment: Can you share your source of reference?

Comment: “It was narrated that ‘Abd-Allaah ibn Mas’ood said: Whoever reads Tabaarak allaahi bi yadihi’l-mulk [i.e., Soorat al-Mulk] every night, Allaah will protect him from the torment of the grave.”

Comment: so your question isn't about reading it everynight (as per the Sahih Hadith) but whether if someone else reads it will have the same sawab or not?

Comment: Also afaik it doesn't apply to those who die on shirk as Allah has stated He will forgive all sins except if one dies on shirk,

Comment: Yeah my question is if a Muslim reads and blows it on a non believer will it have the same effect or no

Comment: The things mentioned in Quran or in Hadith are for the Muslims not for non-Muslims. It is like asking can a non-muslim go to Jannat if he/she fasts.. I hope you get my point.

Comment: Yeah I understand your point thank you. It’s just something I was wondering